# How to create binary indicators for a data.frame given another data.frame of confidence intervals?

Tags: r, apply

I have a data.frame, delta_counts, with values for half a million genes by 500 samples, and another data.frame, ci_data, with confidence intervals for each gene (2 rows, half a million columns).

I want a data.frame/matrix of binary indicators showing if each value in delta_counts falls outside the confidence interval for that specific gene or not.

Here's a small working example but there must be a more efficient way to handle the generation of bin_ind.

```
#generate some data 5 samples by 5 genes
delta_counts <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(-10:10,5,rep=TRUE)))
names(delta_counts) <- sprintf("sample[%s]",seq(1:5))
row.names(delta_counts) <- sprintf("gene[%s]",seq(1:5))

#c.i. function
c.i.func = function(c.i.data){
  #input sample size, sample mean, and sample standard deviation
  n <- length(c.i.data)
  xbar <- mean(as.numeric(c.i.data))
  s <- sd(c.i.data)

  #calculate margin of error
  margin <- qt(0.975,df=n-1)*s/sqrt(n)

  #calculate lower and upper bounds of confidence interval
  c.i.low <- xbar - margin
  c.i.high <- xbar + margin
  
  return(c(c.i.low,c.i.high))
}

#calculate c.i.
ci_data <- apply(delta_counts, 1, c.i.func)
row.names(ci_data) <- c("low","high")

#the data so far
delta_counts
ci_data

#make a binary indicator df/matrix showing which values of delta_counts fall outside the c.i. for that specific gene.
#so for the example 5x5 data shown above it would be 

bin_ind <- delta_counts
bin_ind[] <- 0
for(gene in 1:5) {
  for(sample in 1:5){
    if(delta_counts[gene,sample]<ci_data["low",gene]|delta_counts[gene,sample]>ci_data["high",gene]){
      bin_ind[gene,sample]<-1
    }
  }
}
bin_ind

#but how to do that efficiently over a delta_counts of half a million genes and 500 samples?
```

Comment: I would do it with case_when() or fcase(). fcase() is much faster. I would try it with a small dataset first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should transpose the ci_data into long format (making it the same length as `delta_counts`, and make these both data.tables. You can do a fast merge of the two, using `gene` column, and then use `between()` to check for each column being between the lower and upper bounds. This would return a data.table of boolean columns, which I negate using `==F` and then convert to integer by wrapping in `+()`

```
library(data.table)

df = merge(
  data.table(delta_counts,keep.rownames="gene"),
  data.table(t(ci_data), keep.rownames="gene"),
  by="gene"
)
df[, .(gene, +(between(.SD, low, high)==F)), .SDcols = patterns("sample")]
```

Output:

```
      gene sample.1. sample.2. sample.3. sample.4. sample.5.
1: gene[1]         0         0         1         0         0
2: gene[2]         0         0         0         1         0
3: gene[3]         0         0         1         0         0
4: gene[4]         1         0         0         0         0
5: gene[5]         0         0         1         0         0
```